# Does SIGSEGV default handler do clean-up of stack/heap memory before process termination?

Tags: linux, signals, segmentation-fault

I have declared two variables (one global and other local) in a simple C program, apart from two arrays having different sizes data. I cause a buffer overflow using `strcpy()` routine before making a `return 0;` call. And I see segmentation fault error on the terminal screen.

I know that after receiving this `SIGSEGV` signal, system takes a core dump of process memory and terminates that process, but does system do clean-up (zero-out) of stack/heap memory and other sections like BSS segment, text segment etc?

I guess, in normal termination of a process, system does clean-up (zero-out) of memory but I am not so sure.

I am using `Ubunutu 10.12` and `gcc` to run the program.

Comment: I have been looking at the internet for a few weeks now but I couldn't find any link to any reliable source (like linux documentation) which says, linux does so. Can you provide some link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a Linux [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) terminates (either normally, by calling the `_exit` [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall), e.g. by returning from `main`, or thru a signal like `SIGSEGV`), its [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) ceases to exist.

In practice, the kernel does not zero the former process' memory, it just add the relevant pages to some set of free pages and will reuse these pages later. When reusing a page it will clear it or fill it with appropriate content. All this happens inside the kernel, applications only see appropriately filled (or cleared) pages.

You should read more about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and I invite you to read some good [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) and [advanced linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) books.

Processes see only virtual memory, their address space is set up thru the [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall and may be changed, e.g. with [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) syscall.

Comment: Great answer. "All this happens inside the kernel". I know I should look into linux source code, may be, to see how and what exactly it does but can you give some useful pointer to kernel code? Thanks

Comment: Read first good books on Unix programming. Only when you understand well what a syscall and a a process are (and today you don't understand these) consider diving inside the kernel's internals.

Comment: Yea. I surely should read those books first before diving into kernel mode. Thanks.

Comment: Read also the `intro(2)` and `syscalls(2)` man pages, since syscalls are the only mean for an application to interact with the kernel.